# CSS3 Animation conflicting with CSS3 transition that's triggered by jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, transition

I set up a div so that on click of a button the div would expand upwards to view more content. On second click the button would slide down. I used JS to do this and it works fine.

Secondly I have added an animation to the same div so that at certain points within the animation the div slides up and down. As soon as I added this the animation works fine but the transition and on click of the button to slide the div up/down no longer works and I can't understand why?

Below is the code with both transition and animation applied to the div. There are two fiddles one showing the jQuery slide up/down on its own and the second demonstrating the code below.

Any help would really be appreciated.

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
       <div class="content-wrapper">
           <div class="padLeft">
                <h2>Project Title</h2>
                <div class="crossRotate"> Open </div>
           </div>
           <div class="padLeft">
                <p>Paragraph Goes Here</p>
                <h3>Play Video</h3>
           </div>
       </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    z-index: 1;
}

@-webkit-keyframes titledrop {
    0%, 25%, 50%, 75%, 100%{ bottom: -215px;}
    5%, 20%, 30%, 45%, 55%, 70%, 80%, 95%{ bottom: -90px;}
}

@-moz-keyframes titledrop {
    0%, 25%, 50%, 75%, 100%{ bottom: -215px;}
    5%, 20%, 30%, 45%, 55%, 70%, 80%, 95%{ bottom: -90px;}
}

@keyframes titledrop {
    0%, 25%, 50%, 75%, 100%{ bottom: -215px;}
    5%, 20%, 30%, 45%, 55%, 70%, 80%, 95%{ bottom: -90px;}
}

.content-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    background: red;
    bottom: -90px;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-animation: titledrop 60s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1) infinite;
    -moz-animation: titledrop 60s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1) infinite;
    -o-animation: titledrop 60s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1) infinite;
    -ms-animation: titledrop 60s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1) infinite;
    animation: titledrop 60s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1) infinite;
    -webkit-transition: bottom 1s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: bottom 1s ease-in; 
    -o-transition: bottom 1s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: bottom 1s ease-in;
    transition: bottom 1s ease-in;  
}

.crossRotate {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: blue;
    z-index: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

JS

```
var clicked=true;
$(".crossRotate").on('click', function() {
    if(clicked) {
        clicked=false;
        $(".content-wrapper").css({"bottom": "-90px"});
    } else {
        clicked=true;
        $(".content-wrapper").css({"bottom": "0"});
    }
});
```

jsFiddle One - http://jsfiddle.net/8ZFMJ/64/

jsFiddle Two - http://jsfiddle.net/8ZFMJ/63/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know what is you want but if i understand it, this is u need. I dont it like this, but u know what u want. Here for help. Regards!

```
var clicked=false;
$(".crossRotate").on('click', function(){
    if(clicked){
        clicked=false;
        $(".content-wrapper").animate({"height": "162px"});
    }else{
        clicked=true;
        $(".content-wrapper").animate({"height": "280px"});
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8ZFMJ/65/